# How can I use a Grid View OnRowEditing Event Handler to allow specific cells in the grid view to be edited?

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, gridview

I have a grid view that displays data from a file that our clients upload. After uploading, the file is pushed through several validating methods, and if there are issues with the data, the cells in the grid view are highlighted in red and given a tool tip that briefly describes the problem. I've recently added an "Edit Invalid Entries" button that I want to program to allow the clients to make changes to the erroneous cell(s) in each row, but I'm unsure how to actually set the specific cells to edit mode. I'm fairly new to frontend design (if you want to call this frontend), and I've been unable to find any resources online to help me manually set cells (or even rows) in a grid view to edit mode. The code below loops through each of the rows in the grid view and, if any of its cells are highlighted in red (i.e. there is an error in one of the cells), it is set to visible and the OnRowEditing event is called for that row.

I've looked into the `GridViewEventArgs` class in hopes that I'd be able to make some changes with that, but none of the properties nor methods seem to be of any use for what I'm trying to achieve.

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < grvUpload.Rows.Count; ++i)
{
   if (grvUpload.Rows[i].Cells[0].BackColor.Equals(Color.Red) || grvUpload.Rows[i].Cells[1].BackColor.Equals(Color.Red) || grvUpload.Rows[i].Cells[2].BackColor.Equals(Color.Red) || grvUpload.Rows[i].Cells[3].BackColor.Equals(Color.Red) || grvUpload.Rows[i].Cells[4].BackColor.Equals(Color.Red) || grvUpload.Rows[i].Cells[5].BackColor.Equals(Color.Red))
   {
      grvUpload.Rows[i].Visible = true;
      grvUpload.SetEditRow(i);
   }
   else
   {
      grvUpload.Rows[i].Visible = false;
   }
}

...

protected void grvUpload_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
   // ?
}
```

I expect the line `grvUpload.SetEditRow(i)` to set the i'th row in the grid view to edit mode, but I assume I must do so in the `grvUpload_RowEditing` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in aspx, change asp:BoundField To asp:TemplateField,
for example:

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="xxx">
      <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:TextBox runat="server" Style="text-align: left" ID="id" Width="400px"  Text='<%# Bind("columnName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
       </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

then when gridview bound,you can edit the cell.If you want edit cells after click edit button,like this

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="xxx" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    //use label show message
                    <asp:Label id="id" runat="server" 
                        Text='<%# Bind("columnName") %>'/>                        
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>                   
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" Style="text-align: left" ID="idT" Width="400px"  Text='<%# Bind("columnName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

in .cs grvUpload_RowEditing method,add this,

grvUpload.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
 //maybe you need bind gridview again

Comment: Sorry for the late vote; this is essentially what I implemented and it worked.

Comment: Glad that helped